Odd wrapped column molding in under renovation basement. How to handle?
I have an oddly wrapped lally column in our currently under-progress basement renovation and I am unsure how to handle it. I'm not here to bash the contractor, in fact he's been amazing and accommodating during the whole process considering all the weird workarounds needed in our 1950's basement, but this one item has left me scratching my head.
Issues
There are two issues. First, the ceiling soffit must not be perfectly level as the angle is different, hence the caulk-filled gap and second, since the column edge is lined up with the wall the molding sticks out past the wall and looks weird.
Possible solution
I put together a solution in Photoshop showing how it could be handled. I'm considering removing the top molding and painting as seen in the photochop since the column could look more like an extension of the wall. Does it make sense like this? It would require painting the sides of all the soffits the wall color and bottoms white to be consistent with the walls and ceiling.


Measurements seem off.  Almost like they only measured one side and expected the other three sides to be exact copies.  I also suspect that post is not perfectly plumb.   Finish work requires measurement, measurement, measurement.

Poor workmanship. In most houses, almost nothing is perfectly square and/or plumb all the time. The top moulding needs to be removed and cut to the proper dimensions and miter angles, then re-attached...unless you decide to forgo the moulding entirely... which seems to be a more elegant solution. The moulding may well be covering up other imperfections that will require attention.

Your solution makes perfect sense. That top molding really doesn't fit there overlapping the wall and it's poorly installed. It looks like it's the only top molding in the room so I'd have to ask "why".

Agree. Ask your contractor to remove the top moulding and take care of any problems that the moulding may be covering up.
